# Office Web Apps integrated into Java app

Tags: java, ms-office

I have a Java app that creates and stores some documents online for my users, but every time they need to update the documents and change anything they have to download them and then edit with MS Office and them upload again to the web app. After seeing Office Web App to edit Word, Excel documents I was wondering if there is a way to integrate those editor to my app, so the client will click the file and will be edited by Office online version instead of downloading, editing and uploading.

Comment: Please have a look at the MSWOPI protocol and MSFSSHTTP. You can also see the question/answers listed on my profile. They will help you